# Custom module in nodejs returns "cannot find module" error

Tags: node.js, module, express

I've been writing a little prototype app in the cloud9 ide using express and nodejs.

I was going to re-organize some code into a few custom modules but when I attempt to require them I get an error "cannot find module './lib'

The lib folder is in the root of my site directory. I have 1 file in there "test.js" that has a simple demo to try and get this working.

```
exports.test = function(){
  return 'hello world';  
};
```

It doesn't matter if I put require('./lib') or require('./lib/test') in my app.js, it always throws the same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How is your project organised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two potential errors:

1- require() looks for a file called index.js. So try renaming test.js to index.js might work.

2- Your path is wrong. Is the lib folder in the same folder as the file in which you call the require()?

Comment: hmm any reason why https://github.com/tekpub/congo/blob/master/server.js
is able to reference congo without the file being called "index" ?

Comment: It's because the filename is specified in the require. Using  require('./lib/congo') will look for either the index.js file in a directory called congo, or a congo.js file in the lib directory. If you were to say, require('./lib/congo/') it would only look for index.js in congo directory, and require('./lib/congo.js') will only look for the congo.js file in the lib directory. require('./lib/congo') is ambiguous. I am not sure which order it looks for them in, or which it will use if they're both present.

So you could have done require('./lib/test.js') instead of changing the filename.

Comment: I've tried adding require("./lib/test") and require("./lib/test.js") and both throw the same error I reported in the initial question.

Though this require is being included in a controller. Does that change things?